# jQuery.ajax call works on IE, but fails on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I'm calling a SOAP WebService from JavaScript. In IE my code works, but on Firefox the error function is called with textStatus = "error", xhr.status = 0 and errorThrown empty. I tried different answers, found on SO, but couldn't solve the problem.

```
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: serviceUrl,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", soapAction);
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soap,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            // report success
            success.style.display='block';
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // report error
            fail.style.display='block';
            alert(textStatus + ": " + jqXHR.status + " / " + errorThrown);
        },
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    });
```

Browserversions: IE 9, Firefox 23.0.1

Comment: Are there any errors logged to the Firefox's developer console?

Comment: I checked the Web developer error console, no errors there ...

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the Same origin policy. you cannot use ajax to call external sites. if you really want to use, you have to use JSONP. Or you can use serverside proxy for this. means, call external site in the server side and do ajax call to the that webservice.

Comment: I tried using dataType: "JSONP", but it fails to textStatus = "parsererror", xhr.status = 200 and errorThrown = "Error: jQuery17208070102435807937_1378381185457 was not called"

Comment: Resolved parsererror by using the complete event and then checking the status value. e.g:

complete: function (xhr, status) {
    if (status === 'error' || !xhr.responseText) {
        handleError();
    }
    else {
        var data = xhr.responseText;
        //...
    }
}try this

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand, can you elaborate some more?